# Can I place rooms/equipment specific to non-alchemy professions in my Whiterun House?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've just purchased my first house in Skyrim, the one for 5000 gold in Whiterun. I see that I can add an alchemy lab, but that appears to be it. I'd like to add an enchanting table - is this possible? If not, will it be later on, perhaps in a different house?

Comment: the easiest enchanting table is in riverwood at the inn, its in the hidden celler, behind the big cabnet. just a quick trip away!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @yx. said, you cannot get anything besides what Proventus Avenicci will sell you (the only "useful" thing is the alchemy lab) in Breezehome.

If you're looking for a location to sleep and store things in a non-respawning container that has an enchanting table, I highly recommend the College of Winterhold.  For only 30 gold (to get into the College, which you don't need to pay if you already have the spell she asks for), you get a room in the College's living quarters (with a bed and a chest), which has an enchanting table and alchemy lab in the same zone.

Comment: Nice tip about the College - I'll be sure to check it out once I'm there.

Comment: fyi the spell she asks you to cast is randomized each time, so not necessarily its magelight.  In my 2 times so far, it was fire bolt and healing hands.

Comment: Oh, neat - is it ever more than 30 gold?

Comment: I had `fear` to enter. But where did you get that the container in your college room is non-respawning? Other questions on this site seem to be not so sure.

Comment: Great tip. I just started my "other" character as a mage, and I did not fancy saving up for the house in Whiterun just to get a place to store my stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Its not possible to place a enchanting table into the house.  I've purchased all the upgrades and the only thing is the alchemy table.  I am unsure of other houses as I haven't purchased all of them yet.  (Solitude one costs a whooping 25k gold)

Comment: Thanks. Nice perk if you're an alchemist, and I suppose it makes sense given that they have hundreds of ingredients to store.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about buying houses but if you head to Anise's shack (just west of Riverwood) and kill her, she has a cellar with an enchanting table and alchemy lab. There's also a barrel or two but I'm not sure if it's safe to store stuff in.

Comment: Awesome.  I didn't know about this.  I will kill her tonight after I get off work and eat dinner.